# Socialize or socializing?

Tags: grammar, verb-forms

Again in my exam paper I had to fill this missing sentence:

Many critics also belive that television shoukd be used ...(38) constructive purpose as well as for entertainment.

Which word is correct to fill that missing statement no. (38), socialize, socializing, or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"... used for socially constructive ..."

Neither of the words given fit well at all from a grammatical perspective

Comment: Oh, I know there's that right option in my exam paper, and I missed it.